# Import-once mixin doesn't output any styles at all

Tags: sass

I've got a problem with SCSS or gulp-sass. SCSS from @include is not being compiled to CSS. Only the height is being compiled, but not the background colour or anything put inside the @include.

Below I have some of the File Structure and two sass files, some help would really be appreciated, thanks!

```
// ==============================================
// File structure

/
|_ src
   |_ utils
   |  |_ _mixins.scss
   |
   |_ views
   |  |_ _index.scss
   |
   |_ style.scss

// ==============================================
// _mixins.scss

//
// Mixin to prevent styles from being loaded multiple
// times for components that rely on other components.
//
// @mixin exports
// @param {string} name
//
$modules: () !default;
@mixin exports($name) {
  @if (index($modules, $name) == false) {
    // If module does not exist append name to modules list
    // and write content of module in stylesheet.
    $modules: append($modules, $name);
    @content;
  }
}

// ==============================================
// style.scss

@charset "utf-8";

@import "views/index";

// ==============================================
// _index.scss

@import "../utils/mixins";

#entry {
  height: 100%;
}

@include exports("index") {
  #entry {
    background-color: #ff0000;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with Sass 3.4 the `index()` function does not return `false` when the item doesn't exist in the list.  It returns `null`.  However, even if we fix that, your mixin still won't work as you expect because you're not overwriting the global variable:

```
$modules: () !default;
@mixin exports($name) {
  @if (index($modules, $name) == null) { // modified
    // If module does not exist append name to modules list
    // and write content of module in stylesheet.
    $modules: append($modules, $name) !global; // modified
    @content;
  }
}
```